# Unity3D - Gameobjects generated in runtime not visible on camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to generate a grid using 3D cubes in Unity. The issue I'm having is most likely related to the camera/render settings, but I'm unable to find where or what to change.
The "lines" are generated as expected and show up as intended. However, some are invisible until I start changing the camera size property (it is set to orthographic projection). Once I start adjusting that property, I find that some objects are shown with different widths (which shouldn't be happening considering it is orthographic).

```
GameObject go_grid = new GameObject("Grid");

for(int i = -24; i < 24; i++) {
    GameObject go_gridline = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    go_gridline.transform.position = new Vector3 (i*2.7f, 0, 0);
    go_gridline.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0.2f, 1, 75);
    go_gridline.transform.parent = go_grid.transform;
}
```

Objects not visible

[image: Objects not visible]

Objects of varying size

[image: Objects of varying size]

I'm guessing it has something to do with culling or something of the kind, but can't find where to tinker. Also, the varying widths are stumping me.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: is it intended that both images are the same?

Comment: I would claim this on just being render artifacts .. they look as expected when zooming in

Comment: @derHugo not, those were supposed to be different. In the first one there should be some lines missing.
Is there a way to make renders more consistent, or is that something we have to live with?

Comment: I'm not sure .. you might try some anti-aliasing ... but in general it is ofcourse difficult for the renderer to e.g. render a line that has with < 1 pixel .. also if the line is exactly between to pixels should it rather disappear or be 2 pixel wide? I think that something like this is happening here